# RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection. GPIO.BOTH Raspberry Pi datalogger

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio

I am coding a datalogger using a Raspberry Pi and am starting to test my code but now keep getting an error saying 'RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection'. Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import csv
from csv import writer

# endTime = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)



def my_callback(channel):
     data_writer([GPIO.input(40), datetime.datetime.now()])      # writes the detected
     # edge event to a CSV file with columns of rise/fall and the date & time of detection


if __name__ == '__main__':

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)       # set up GPIO numbering (BOARD = physical pins on Pi)
    GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN)         # set physical pin 40 as input


# create CSV file to write edge detection data to called Datalogger, with data on new line
    with open('/media/pi/KINGSTON/datalogger.csv', 'w', newline='') as Datalogger:
        data_writer = writer(Datalogger)

        data_writer.writerow(["Edge type", "Date & Time"])       # create headers in CSV file


        GPIO.add_event_detect(40, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback)     # edge detection function
        # detects both rise and fall in signal on pin 40, then runs my callback


        while True:
# main program loop here - loops detection of edges then runs my callback
          # if datetime.datetime.now() >= endTime:
               #break
          time.sleep(0.01)
              # exit()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've seen that I might need to run this as root but am not sure how to do so.
Many thanks.

Comment: Your code runs on my Pi3B+ (had to add 'import time') although I haven't got anything connected to pin 40. Are you running the latest Raspbian Stretch fully updated?

Comment: Is SPI disabled under Interfaces in Raspberry Pi Configuration as that is also on pin 40 https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin40_gpio21 ?

Comment: I have version 4.14.71-v7 installed. How would I run this script as root user? (I'm new to python). I haven't disabled SPI I will see if that works thanks.

Comment: SPI has always been disabled by the looks of it. Do I need to enable remote access of GPIO?

Comment: Should not need to run as root, no remote access of GPIO not required.

Comment: Ok, what happens when you run the code?

Comment: Writes headers to csv file, then loops.

Comment: Mine creates the CSV with headers but just won't detect any events to add the CSV. Don't understand why..

Comment: I think the problem may be a thread being created by GPIO.add_event_detect not being closed. If you reboot and run from command line all works - tested with button attached to pin 40. If you break out, re-run and get the error a reboot then solves the problem again. (had to add data_writer.writerow to my_callback)

Comment: Thanks for testing and for the feedback! I will have to test it tomorrow now and try running it from the command line. Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work reliably on my Pi3B with a button connected to pin 40 with a resistor to 3.3V. If I use Thonny this can re-introduce the 'failed to add edge detection error', running from command line seems to work fine.

I've added GPIO.PUD_DOWN to pull pin 40 low as in my case it should normally be low unless pressed.

I've added bouncetime=10 to the add_event_detect - don't fully understand the need for this however some posts suggest it helps solve a threading issue.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import csv
from csv import writer
import time

# endTime = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)

def my_callback(channel):
     data_writer.writerow([GPIO.input(40), datetime.datetime.now()])      # writes the detected
     # edge event to a CSV file with columns of rise/fall and the date & time of detection


if __name__ == '__main__':

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)       # set up GPIO numbering (BOARD = physical pins on Pi)
    GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)         # set physical pin 40 as input


# create CSV file to write edge detection data to called Datalogger, with data on new line
    with open('/home/pi/datalogger.csv', 'w', newline='') as Datalogger:
        data_writer = writer(Datalogger)

        data_writer.writerow(["Edge type", "Date & Time"])       # create headers in CSV file


        GPIO.add_event_detect(40, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=10)     # edge detection function
        # detects both rise and fall in signal on pin 40, then runs my callback


        while True:
# main program loop here - loops detection of edges then runs my callback
          # if datetime.datetime.now() >= endTime:
               #break
          time.sleep(0.01)
              # exit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give mine a try tomorrow and see how it goes. I think the bouncetime is due to the connections of the battery once pressed. It can detect slight connections and disconnections when you press the button making it think its been pressed multiple times whereas it's been pressed once with just slightly inaccurate contacts within the button. So the bouncetime is a type of delay **I think**.

Comment: Hi @CoderMike, I'm having trouble running it again. Can you explain how and where you're running the code from? Thanks.

Comment: Run from a terminal window 'python3 test.py'

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It says directory or file does not exist. In the terminal I've also done 'cd <path to my python script>' then 'python3 DataloggerV2.py'. This runs the program but still gives the runtime error: failed to add event. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Did you do a fresh reboot, then run the python program? What is actually connected to pin 40?

Comment: It has been switched off and on again and then I ran the program but it still didn't work. I have a signal generator inputting a square wave signal into pin 40. From what I've read it seems you need to run the program in root mode to access the GPIO's on the newer versions of python. When you ran the code did you get a CSV populated with data?

Comment: Yes, I got data populated in the csv. What voltages and frequency are your signal?  Can you test with a button and resistor connected to 3.3V.

Comment: It's 5V at 1Hz. Should I save my python script to a certain directory and do something else in the terminal? Might be able to test with a button but not today unfortunately.

Comment: 5V is too much for a GPIO (3.3V max). You might have damaged that input.

Comment: Ah that's probably a slight problem... and a stupid mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've checked the GPIO pin and it still works. I've also tested the code that you used using a button instead of a signal generator and it still comes up with Failed to add event detection. I've run the code from within the script editor and also from the raspberry pi terminal by typing in cd <path to python file> then python3 DataloggerV2.py, and it still doesn't populate the CSV with data. Can you think of anything else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run it from the terminal as soon as you rebooted? What GPIO version are you using: import RPi.GPIO as GPIO print(GPIO.VERSION) I'm using 0.6.3

Comment: I've just got it to work! It's slightly temperamental but I think that's because of the button I'm using. Going to try it with the signal later so hopefully that works. And yes that was from running it from the terminal after rebooting. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You might want to update to 0.6.4 (pip3 install RPi.GPIO) release notes say they've fixed some thread issues. Please mark the answer if its working.

Comment: I have that update and everything is now working with the signal generator! Answer has been marked. Thanks